# If statement with ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, contextmenu

I'm using WinForms. Inside my WinForms application I have a contextMenuStrip
if you rightclick on the picturebox, contextMenuStrip will appear with a list of items you can click on. How do i call the "sizeMEToolStripMenuItem_Click" method into another method.

example:

[image]

```
 private void sizeMEToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(sizeMEToolStripMenuItem.isclicked) //.isClicked is somthing i made up
     {
       e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, movingPoint); <- This draws and shows image
     }
    else 
    {
      //e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, movingPoint); <- Hide this image
    }

 } 


private void pictureBox1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
 //e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, movingPoint);

}
```

Comment: Edit the context strip, double click on the menu item you want a click event  to happen on, and then write the click handler.

Comment: When you clicked the item obviously you are clicked it, what do you need? Do you need `Checked` property?

Comment: I rewrote my code to make it more clear. How would I use (DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, movingPoint) when the user clicks on the event handler.

Comment: `sizeMEToolStripMenuItem.isclicked` would always be true since you are inside the click event handler. In order to trigger a redraw on the picturebox, just use `pictureBox1.Invalidate()` in the click handler, which will trigger the paint event to be called. `e.Graphics` is not available in the click handler and should only be used in the paint method.

Comment: The Click event of the menu would set a flag, `sizeME = true;` or something like that, and then invalidate: `pictureBox1.Invalidate();`  Then in your drawing code, you check that flag to determine what you want to draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply hanlde click event of that Item and put your codes in the Click event handler.

Open designer, select your context menu, select `sizeMEToolStripMenuItem` and double click on it. This way when you click on `sizeMEToolStripMenuItem` this method runs.

You can also set `CheckOnClick` property of `sizeMEToolStripMenuItem` to true and check value of `Checked` propery.

```
private void sizeMEToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if( sizeMEToolStripMenuItem.Checked )
    {  
        //Do what you need, for example:
        //MessageBox.Show("checked");
        //To force paint event trigger you can uncomment next line:
        //pictureBox1.Invalidate();  
    }
}
```

To force paint event trigger, call this method in click event:

```
pictureBox1.Invalidate();
```

In paint event if you need to check if the item has been clicked, check value of `Checked`:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if( sizeMEToolStripMenuItem.Checked )
    {  
         //Do somethings
    }     
}
```

You can also set `Checked` property value in code.

Comment: I know about this, but I need to call this method somewhere else when its clicked.

Comment: The event handler does this for you. When you click on menu, the codes of this method will execute.

Comment: @taji01 Let me know if you have any question about answer.

Comment: I rewrote my code to make it more clear. How would I use (DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, movingPoint) when the user clicks on the event handler.

Comment: You can simply check if `Checked` property is true then you do your job. you should set `CheckOnClick` to true.

Comment: How would i remove the paint I created in the pictureBox1_paint method. when you click on the contexmenustrip

Comment: @taji01 I think this is another question, but if I understand your question correctly you can simply not to draw it, or you can use `e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White)` for example.

Comment: @taji01 this post answers to **How to check if a ContextMenuItem is clicked** and you can simply write any logic based on this. Hope you find it helpful:)